# Im having cogs error in my python program for a discord bot. "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './cogs'"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I'm having this problem in Visual code, programing a discord bot and when I run it I get this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users----\Desktop\EinsteinBot-master (1)\EinsteinBot-master\bot.py", line 18, in 
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './cogs'

here is the cogs code part:

`for file in os.listdir("./cogs"): if file.endswith(".py"): name = file[:-3]`

Comment: The current directory does not contain a subdirectory named `cogs`.  (The current directory is not necessarily the same directory where the python code is located.)

Comment: what should I change in my code? please specify more

Comment: You should change the `listdir()` call to use the full directory path for cogs, instead of assuming it's in the current directory.

Comment: By "Visual code" did you mean Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? If VS Code, the correct tag is `visual-studio-code`.

Comment: @AndrewF Visual Studio Code